# How to display direction of track with arrows using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I would like to display track on the map using OpenLayers in the way like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/*DR*/hgCUq/1/light/](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/hgCUq/1/light/)

How to show direction of the track with arrows here? Any other approach would be great as well.

I googled https://github.com/Sirtrack/PointTrackWithArrows but this project looks buggy and conflicts with OpenLayers.Layer.PointTrack

Comment: thank you Mapperz - is some code sample available?

Comment: @Mapperz the old link is defunct, moved to: http://oobrien.com/2013/10/

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of https://github.com/Sirtrack/PointTrackWithArrows . It's basic but functional and have been using it for some years (thanks to the original author!). 
I'm now looking for something similar to work with OpenLayers 3.
If you're still interested, just leave a comment.

Comment: For OpenLayers 3, You can try the official sample http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/line-arrows.html. The example uses an image for the arrow. I did not like the fact to use an image when I need proportional arrows (although I could do image resizing using Canvas...), so I worked on a version with an arrow "as a triangle" using `ol.style.regularShape`. You can see it at https://rawgit.com/ThomasG77/datadouane_raw/master/flux_vin_export_mars_2015.html

Comment: Here's a link to @ThomasG77's source code https://github.com/ThomasG77/datadouane_raw/blob/master/assets/js/app-debug.js